# Javascript accordion one section open

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, accordion

I am using a Wordpress plugin that configures a accordion. 
I would like to have one section open at all times as a default.

If I change state to open, it opens all, but I can manually close all of them.
This is not the solution I am looking for.

Solution: one open by default.

Despite trying several things, I could not alter the code to make it work.
Can someone please help me.

```
$id = ($id <> '') ? " id='" . esc_attr( $id ) . "'" : '';
$class = ($class <> '') ? esc_attr( ' ' . $class ) : '';

$divClass = ($state == 'close') ? 'et-learn-more' : 'et-learn-more et-open';
$hClass = ($state == 'close') ? 'heading-more' : 'heading-more open';
$divClass .= ' clearfix';

$output = "<div{$id} class='{$divClass}{$class}'>
                <h3 class='{$hClass}'>" . esc_html( $caption ) . "<span class='et_learnmore_arrow'><span></span></span></h3>
                <div class='learn-more-content'>{$content}</div>
            </div>";

return $output;
```

Comment: This isn't even JavaScript... Do you know what you're doing?

Comment: Not anymore. I feel lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going out from the assumption that your example code is inside a loop, thus all you need to do is to ensure that when you hit a certain `id` (the one you want to keep open), that it gets the status of open at all times.

Assuming, say, the `id` of the section you want to keep open is `3`, this is what you could do:

```
if ($id == 3)
    $state = 'open';
```

Insert this statement on top of the code block you added to your question.

As I don't know what else is influencing the variable `$state`, make sure it's not being changed anywhere else, so that your statement above always remains true ensuring the section to always remain open.

Comment: That didn't work.

If my h3 has a class="open", it stays open.
It has something to do with the status == open, but I don't know how to adjust this.

Comment: i don't understand, didn't you want it to stay open?

Comment: It want one section to remain open, not all.

Currently I can manually close and open all sections.

Comment: have you followed what i wrote? i specifically mentioned that you have to force only one id (the one of your selection) to always have the state open... if you're not providing more details of what else is there in the plugin, any further help will only be guess work...

Comment: this is not a plugin, but a theme... either way, you're going to have to get through this alone following my advice above... look for the right id number and ensure state is not being updated elsewhere in the code for that id to remain open at all times...

Comment: And then the ToggledContent

http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/TheProfessional/shortcodes/#toggled

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will try some variations on the code.